# Materialize Modal not working, staying open

Tags: html, css, laravel, materialize

I'm trying to use the materialize modal in my laravel app, I've got a blade file called skeleton which I put all my "scripts" in and stylesheets etc. That yeilds the sections which I define in my single blade files. That works great, however I've had loads of issues with materialize lately.

When I try to use the modal, I use this code from the docs:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.modal').modal();
        });
```

That's at the bottom of my skeleton file and shows at the bottom of every file. I've tried putting it in my file itself and it didn't work.

My HTML looks like this:

```
 @if($auth >= 5) <a href="#modal1" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green right modal-trigger"
                href="#modal1"> Create</a>
            @endif
```

at the bottom of the blade file:

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
</div>
```

My modal appears on screen, but it's automatically "shown" and when I click the open button it doesn't do anything. I'm just using the demo modal, I'll customize it when I can get it to work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

For opening a modal please use the below code

```
$('.modal').modal('show');
```

For closing a modal please use the below code

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

It's opening automatically because of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal();
});
```

Whenever the doument is ready then it's opens the modal.

On click

```
@if($auth >= 5) <a href="#modal1" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green right modal-trigger" href="#modal1"> Create</a>
@endif
```

Open the modal using `$('.modal').modal('show');`

Comment: I've made this code, it doesn't work though. 
`$(".modal-trigger").click(function() {
            $('.modal').modal('show');
        })`

Comment: @flugscoding are you getting any error in browser console? Can you check whether the click method is getting triggered?

Comment: This code is incorrect. There is no show and hide in materialize. It is open and close.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first up, why two href's on the modal trigger?

```
 @if($auth >= 5) <a href="#modal1" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green right modal-trigger"
                href="#modal1"> Create</a>
            @endif
```

Take one off, and let's take it from there.

The answer above incorrectly states that the init below opens the modal:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal();
});
```

This is just the initialisation, it plugs into the JS to allow it to work.

```
<!-- this is the initialisation -->
$('.modal').modal();
<!-- this is instruction to open -->
$('.modal').modal('open');
```

Check the pen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/OJVmPwQ) for the two commands, comment each out to see what happens.

Modals are closed by default, and are triggered by clicking the `.modal-trigger` or using the open command above..

Answer (score 0):

I was being stupid, I had bootstrap js linked for some reason and they were conflicting. Sorry to waste anyone's time.